# how to write endpoint configuration in wcf Programmatically c#

Tags: c#, wcf

I m trying to create end point configuration Programmatically, below is the config file generated, I want to create same configuration using c# programmatically.I want to set bindingConfiguration,contract,name,binding,address through programatically.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFakeService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:55536/FakeService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFakeService" contract="ChannelAdam.Wcf.BehaviourSpecs.TestDoubles.IFakeService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IFakeService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it programmatically? I recommend to use config-file- based configuration as much as possible for both wcf-server and client sides (sometimes it is hard but rarely not possible).

Comment: according project requirements we cannot have config file, that's the reason I m want to create end point configuration programmatically

Comment: this is strange (if it is not some technology restrictions), you are running the risk you will reinventing the weel (to support custom configuration).

Answer (score 3):

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding() {
    Name = "BasicHttpBinding_IFakeService",
    MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647
};

var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:55536/FakeService.svc");
MyInterfaceClient client = new MyInterfaceClient(binding, endpoint);
```